# Kubernetes API for configmap

Tags: java, kubernetes, kubectl, creation, configmap

I could get the kubectl working for creating configmap with a set of files with below command

```
kubectl create configmap configmap2 --from-file foldername
```

where foldername contains files with keys and values

Now I want to create a K8s config map with the same folder using Java. I dont want to use any libraries. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that but it is not that easy - you will have to:

- List all files (you can use `java.nio.file.Files`)
- Create base64 representation of the files (use `java.util.Base64` for this)
- Create a JSON representing the files and the meta-data (you will have to use String concatenation for this). The JSON should look like the output of:

  ```
  kubectl create configmap configmap2 --from-file foldername --dry-run -o json
  ```
- Post that to the Kubernetes API Server with the correct authentication (using the new [HTTP client](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html))

It would be easier to use a Kubernetes Java client (e.g.: [fabric8io client](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client), [official Kubernetes client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java)).

Comment: Used a k8s client. THanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the API request that you have to make to the Kubernetes API server to create a ConfigMap:

> [`POST /api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/configmaps`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#create-configmap-v1-core)

The data must be a ConfigMap JSON object as specified [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#configmap-v1-core).

If you don't use a library, you must also include the correct credentials in the request, which is usually a token (`Authorization: Bearer <token>`) or a certificate.

**Tip:**

You can use `kubectl create configmap -v 10 configmap2 --from-file foldername` (note `-v 10`) to see the exact HTTP request that kubectl makes to the API server.